# Wpf Popup loses focus but stays opened

Tags: wpf, popup, focus

I have the following Popup:

```
<Popup Name="popupBind"
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               Helpers:FocusHelper.IsFocused="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                       Path=IsOpen,
                                                       Mode=OneWay}"
               HorizontalOffset="-30"
               IsOpen="{Binding IsBindingBegun,
                                Mode=TwoWay}"
               Placement="Bottom"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=bindButton}"
               StaysOpen="False"
               >
            <Border Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static Styles:CommonStyles.ButtonsPanelBackgroundKey}}"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Padding="0">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <TemplateSelectors:VersionRangeDataTemplateSelector x:Key="VersionRangeDataTemplateSelector" />
                        <Converters:RangeToVisibilityConverter x:Key="RangeToVisibilityConverter" />
                    </StackPanel.Resources>

                    <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,2"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>

                        <Button Command="{Binding BindCommand}"
                               >
                        </Button>
                        <Button Command="{Binding BindCommand}"
                                >
                        </Button>
                        <Button Command="{Binding BindCommand}"
                                >
                        </Button>
                        <Button Command="{Binding BindCommand}"
                                >
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <ItemsControl Margin="10,2,5,5"
                                  Focusable="False"
                                  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource VersionRangeDataTemplateSelector}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VersionsVm.TempRanges}">
                        <ItemsControl.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                            </Style>

                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
                            </Style>

                            <DataTemplate x:Key="TwoDistinctVersionsRangeTemplateKey">
                                <Grid Margin="2,4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="_1" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="_2" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="_3" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="_4" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="_5" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="_6" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="_7" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding IncludeStartEdge, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0,5,0">
                                        <TextBlock.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IncludeStartEdge}" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="[" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IncludeStartEdge}" Value="False">
                                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="(" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                    </TextBlock>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               Text="{Binding FromVersionName}"
                                               TextAlignment="Left" />

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"
                                               Width="10"
                                               Margin="5,0"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="-"
                                               TextAlignment="Center" />

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               Text="{Binding ToVersionName}"
                                               TextAlignment="Left" />

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Margin="5,0,2,0">
                                        <TextBlock.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IncludeEndEdge}" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="]" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IncludeEndEdge}" Value="False">
                                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value=")" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                    </TextBlock>

                                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="6" IsChecked="{Binding IncludeEndEdge, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate x:Key="FixedVersionRangeTemplateKey">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="2,4"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="{Binding FromVersionName}"
                                               TextAlignment="Left" />
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel.Visibility>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RangeToVisibilityConverter}">
                                                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                    <Binding />
                                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" />
                                                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </StackPanel.Visibility>
                                        <RadioButton Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                                      AncestorType=UserControl},
                                                                       Path=DataContext.VersionsVm.ChangeTempRangeTypeCommand}"
                                                                                                              Content="&lt;" />
                                        <RadioButton Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                                      AncestorType=UserControl},
                                                                       Path=DataContext.VersionsVm.ChangeTempRangeTypeCommand}"                                                         
                                                     Content="&lt;=" />
                                        <RadioButton Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                                      AncestorType=UserControl},
                                                                       Path=DataContext.VersionsVm.ChangeTempRangeTypeCommand}"                                                         
                                                     Content="="
                                                     IsChecked="True" />
                                        <RadioButton Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                                      AncestorType=UserControl},
                                                                       Path=DataContext.VersionsVm.ChangeTempRangeTypeCommand}"
                                                                                                              Content="&gt;=" />
                                        <RadioButton Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                                      AncestorType=UserControl},
                                                                       Path=DataContext.VersionsVm.ChangeTempRangeTypeCommand}"
                                                                                                              Content="&gt;" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.Resources>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

I have a very strange issue with it.
When I hit Tab, Left or Right focus leaves popup and goes to the parent window. Popus stays opened.
I do not know why this happens. But I've got broken keyboard navigation.
The only thing I can suspect to be the reason is that parent of Popup is UserControl hosted inside winforms ElementHost.
I have no idea how to debug this problem so I appreciate any helpful hints.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What sets the IsBindingBegun property?

Comment: It's not that binding =) It's the binding of the entities - making them relevant. Nothing common with WPF Binding besides the name.

Answer (score 3):

Having a Binding on IsOpen can override the StaysOpen behavior. I can't tell without seeing more but if that IsOpen binding is persisting a `True` value from its source that would keep the Popup open no matter what happens with the focus.

Comment: Yes, binding for IsOpen is the reason, I guess. But I don't know why keyboard navigation doesn't work.

Comment: Again, I don't know what's going on with the rest of the code, but I suspect that the FocusHelper.IsFocused binding may be messing with your focus as well since that's going to stay True as long as the Popup is showing and might be preventing the contained controls from ever getting focus.