# Invisible opened popup

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

Second day fighting this issue.

To reproduce, create new WPF application,  xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" MouseMove="Button_MouseMove"/>
    <Popup x:Name="popup" StaysOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Center">
        <TextBlock>Some random text</TextBlock>
    </Popup>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding (Popup.IsOpen), ElementName=popup}">Popup</CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

and code

```
private void Button_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Mouseover button to open popup, click elsewhere to close. Click button to have bug: popup is **IsOpen == true** (can be seen on checkbox or with breakpoint in handler), while it is invisible.

WTF?

And my original problem is, it seems, what **setting `IsOpen` is not instant**. To example, when I try to set it to `false` in `Popup`'s `MouseMove` event, then I get `MouseEnter` and `MouseMove` events of `Button` fired right during that

```
IsOpen = true;
```

Same with setting it to `true`, there are 2 (!) `MouseMove` events occurs, put this line into event handler to see it

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("M");
```

There will be 2 M in the *Output* window of VS, while `Popup` (when `StayOpen=false`) suppose to capture mouse events and it does, but **not immediately**.

Can someone explain me what it going on? I want no events to occurs **during** (or shortly after? how to check if this is true?) setting `IsOpen`. Tried already dozens of things: `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`, variables, timers, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wpf Popup loses focus but stays opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404897/wpf-popup-loses-focus-but-stays-opened). See the answer there: most likely the binding to IsOpen causes the StaysOpen property to not function correctly...

Comment: @qqbenq, has nothing to do with focus. Binding here is to only demonstrate the problem (remove it and use breakpoint = same problem).

Comment: `A Popup does not automatically open when the mouse pointer moves over its parent object. If you want a Popup to automatically open, use the ToolTip or ToolTipService class. For more information, see ToolTip Overview.` taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @NETscape, yep. It doesn't. I am opening it *manually*.

Comment: +1 for nicely demonstrating your problem. I can verify that there *is* a problem here. However, please tell me what you *actual* program requirements are and perhaps we can find another way for you to fulfil them.

Comment: @Sheridan, I'd be happy if there is one. I am trying to create nice nagivation panel (to navigate among 2d-matrix of views): horizontal row of buttons, when you mouse-over a button, then a vertical list of buttons appears. It suppose to be as simple as displaying `Popup` when mouseovering button. Yet it doesn't works. Keyword - invisible Popup with `IsOpen=true`. I tried some workarounds, to example, always closing `Popup` before displaying, but then I found out this freeky thing with events. So my *nice* idea looks clunky, flickering, etc. =(

Comment: Yeah, I had the flickering too in my investigations... I'll look into it if I get time.

Comment: @Sinatr, what do you expect on button press? Should the `Popup` stay opened or is it OK for it to close?

Comment: @icebat, button press is just to demonstrate what there are issues with `Popup`. I found that `Popup` can become invisible if you: 1) close it with `IsOpen=false`, 2) while mouse is hovering button 3) this button tries to show `Popup` in one of the mouse events (`MouseMove` or `MouseEnter`) by setting `IsOpen=true`. `Popup` will become invisible (on screen), while it has `IsOpen=true`. So here I come with demo project. I assume, what fix may be then re-used in my project. Or at least, gives me idea how to continue, because right now I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are right with the asynchronous assumption. During the focus loss, the value of `IsOpen` is set to false, but the `MouseMove` of the button triggers to set it open again. Some strange magic inside then breaks the code.

2 possible solutions I found, depending on your needs:

1. Explicitly set `IsOpen` to `false`, after the popup closed (bash async)
2. #1 + Disable the button during the popup `IsOpen == true`

The first approach will hide the popup during clicking on the button. The second approach will come along with a slight flickering - when rapidly clicking the button - but it keeps the popup open:

For the first approach, use the following event handlers (you might not check the property first):

```
private void Button_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void Popup_OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (popup.IsOpen)
        popup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

For the second approach, use a `BoolInvertConverter` and bind it one way to the popup:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding (Popup.IsOpen), ElementName=popup, Converter={StaticResource BoolInvertConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: `Closed` and setting `IsOpen=false` is a cheat, but it works perfectly, thanks! I already solve the problem with click by displaying `Popup` on top of that button (with same button as one below), so you can't *click* it =P

Comment: @Sinatr Yeah, it's much more a workaround/cheat, rather than a fix. If you want to fix it, go to Microsoft and dig around in their code! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, `MouseMove` and `MouseEnter` are both called when you press the button (even if with Spacebar key), so this leads to situation when `Popup` is trying to close while having `IsOpen` set to true at the same time. The simple solution could be to divide this two events.

One possible way can be to stick to `MouseEnter` and open `Popup` just once while hovering over given `Button`. Just as example:

```
private Button currentPopupHolder;
private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   var btn = sender as Button;
   if (currentPopupHolder != btn)
   {
      popup.IsOpen = true;
      currentPopupHolder = btn;
   }
}

private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   currentPopupHolder = null;
}
```

While the same `Button` generates this events `Popup` should not be opened more than once (including the time when the button is pressed).

Comment: Idea is good, but explicit `IsOpen=true` in `OnClosed` event solution from @Herdo is superior.