# MouseEnter event does not fire on a Popup control after a mouse click on the Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I was testing a Popup control in WPF with the following code

```
<Window x:Class="Popup1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Popup1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="250">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap">You can use a popup to provide a link for a specific 
            <Run TextDecorations="Underline" MouseEnter="ContentElement_OnMouseEnter">
                term
            </Run>
        </TextBlock>
        <Popup Name="popLink" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Mouse" MaxWidth="200"
           PopupAnimation="Slide" AllowsTransparency="True">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                For more information, see 
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term" Click="Hyperlink_OnClick">Wikipedia</Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

and the handlers

```
private void ContentElement_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    popLink.IsOpen = true; 
}

private void Hyperlink_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Process.Start(((Hyperlink) sender).NavigateUri.ToString());
}
```

The result is a trivial window that contains a `textblock` with a link to a popup control that visually appears when the mouse hovers over the link to the popup. 
The normal behavioris the popup to stay visible until a mouse click. This works fine as long as the mouse click is not on the link to the popup

The strange behaviorthat i can't explain happens when i click the mouse over the link to the popup.Then, the popup closes ( as expected ) but it never appears again when the mouse hovers over the link (as it should).

Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: For me this happens when the `popup.IsOpen` is already `true` but the popup is not visible for some reason.

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491382/invisible-opened-popup So it seems there is a race condition between the popup closing and the mouse entering the textblock below the popup (because it is closing), so it will set `IsOpen=true` again while the popup closing is not finished. (Just my assumption of what is going on)

Answer (score 2):

As commented, the reason is probably a race condition between closing popup and re-opening because the mouse is over the textblock. You can prevent this situation by delaying the popup open action until current work is completed:

```
private void ContentElement_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => popLink.IsOpen = true));
}
```

---

Regarding your title text: the MouseEnter event is actually fired (debug it!), just the action within is not working as expected because the popup is in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Although your proposal solves the main problem it creates a flickering of the popup (it shows up two times in sequence in every mouse click on the link). I also don't understand why you resorted to the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method and the refered delay. After seeing your comment above and with some tweacking i find the following solution better in terms of visual behaviour.

Comment: I resorted to the solution because it delivers the promise: on every mouse enter, open the popup. The reason why you like the other solution better is, because you don't like what you programmed. If you don't want to re-open the popup right away when clicking to close, you can just as well change the dispatcher call: `if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => popLink.IsOpen = true));` or do it as you found in the link. I saw no need to re-post the linked solution.

Answer (score 0):

After some tweaking the best behaviour is achieved if we add an extra event (comparing to the initial code) handler for the Popup Close event that sets the IsOpen property to false when the popup closes

```
private void PopLink_OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       if (popLink.IsOpen) {
            popLink.IsOpen = false;
       }            
    }
```

and the ammenment in XAML

```
<Popup Name="popLink" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Mouse" MaxWidth="200"
       PopupAnimation="Slide" AllowsTransparency="True"
           Closed="PopLink_OnClosed">
        <Border Background="Bisque">
            <TextBlock Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap">
            For more information, see 
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term" Click="Hyperlink_OnClick">Wikipedia</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```